# Error estimation of $\alpha_s$

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization, quantum-chromodynamics, strong-force

I have calculated the strong coupling constant $\alpha_s$ using and approximate solution of the Renormalization Group Equation
$$\mu_R^2\frac{d\alpha_s}{d\mu_R^2}=-(b_0 \alpha_s^2 + b_1\alpha_s^3 + b_2\alpha_s^4 + ...)$$
given by
$$\alpha(\mu_R^2)=\frac{1}{b_0t}(1-\frac{b_1}{b_0^2}\frac{\ln t}{t}+\frac{b_1^2(\ln^2 t-\ln t -1)+b_0b_2}{b_0^4t^2}-...)$$
with $t\equiv\ln\frac{\mu_R^2}{\Lambda^2}$
and using as $\mu_R$ as the center of mass energy of the $c \bar c$ ($\mu_R=\frac{m_c}{2}c_F\alpha_s$) meson, which also depends on $\alpha_s$ like $M_{c\bar c}=2m_c-(c_F\alpha_s)^2\frac{m_c}{2} $ (and taking $M_{c\bar c}$ as some experimental value). You can find the explanation [here](http://pdg.lbl.gov/2015/reviews/rpp2015-rev-qcd.pdf)).

My question is: how can I estimate the error commited taking just the first term or the first two terms in the $\alpha(\mu_R^2)$ equation?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is a way of getting from first principles an error estimación for field theory predictions. I thought that knowing that in puré yang-mills was almost the thing that you needed for getting the millenium prize. I heard that in the QCD-pheno comunity they have some euristics, but they aren't first principle thing. I'll like to know the real answer to this question, so I will make a little noise with this almost-fake answer.

Answer (score 0):

The terms in the equation for $\alpha_s(\mu_R^2)$ as cited gives schematically the one loop, two loop etc running couplings in terms of $\Lambda_{\text{QCD}}$ and RGE coefficients $b_i$.

$\Lambda_{\text{QCD}}$ is a beast carrying many 'indices' in the sense that a numerical value attached to it depends on the order of the running, the number of active flavours and a reference scale $\mu_o^2$, commonly taken to be the $Z$ mass.  In Schwartz's 'Quantum Field Theory and the Standard Model', he calculates values for this parameter at various loop orders assuming a *constant* flavour running with $n_f=5$ using the well known world average value for $\alpha_s(M_z^2) = 0.1181 \pm 0.0013.$

This approximate solution for the runnings assumes a constant number of active flavours throughout the evolution which introduces an error since no flavour decoupling mechanisms are in play. The package `RunDec` has in built functionality which will do this decoupling for you automatically. Comparing its output for $\alpha_s$ at e.g two loop with various values of  $\mu_R^2$ against that obtained using the naive 'poor mans' approach formula yields percentage differences starting off in the range of $\sim 11$% and growing as $\mu_R^2$ is increased.

Clearly for precision calculations needed today for descriptions of LHC phenomena, this is a noticeable error and so such a formula is not to be used in practice.